# Cannot find symbol System.console().readInt();

Tags: java, io

This is my code:

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    String enter = "Enter";
    String resolve = "Resolve";
    String store = "Store";

    // if file doesn't exist
    int nextjob = 1;
    int jobnumber = nextjob;
    int phonenumber = System.console().readInt();
    int numberoflines = System.console().readInt();
    String problem = System.console().readLine();
    int time = System.console().readInt();

    String command = System.console().readLine();
    if(command.equals(store)){
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("openjobs.txt");
        writer.println(nextjob);
        writer.println(jobnumber);
        writer.println(phonenumber);
        writer.println(numberoflines);
        writer.println(problem);
        writer.println(time);
        writer.close();
    }
  }
}
```

This is the output:

```
Main.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
        int phonenumber = System.console().readInt();
                                          ^
symbol:   method readInt()
location: class Console
```

Comment: There is no `readInt()` method in `Console` class. What do you want to do? Do you want to read user input?

Comment: Is there any method say readInt() ? I guess no.

Comment: I want to read user input as an int, like readLine().

Comment: I´d also consider to not use `System.console()`, because it might return null depending on the enviroment it´s beeing executed on.

Comment: Use [`scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Comment: @Kevin Esche How would I get     readLine() to work without     system.console()?

Comment: You can use - System.console().reader().read();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) and [`Scanner.nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) method to take only Integer as input from the user.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int anyNumber = sc.nextInt();
```

If the user gives an input which is not an integer, it will throw an [`InputMismatchException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html).